# fedora /usr/share/dict/words file

Tags: fedora

is there a way I can install `/usr/share/dict/words` file for Fedora 11 , (it should be a list of dictionary English words?)?

Comment: ditto for ubuntu? apt-get install words didn't do anything...

Answer (score 12):

```
yum install words
```

Answer (score 6):

In general, if you want to install `/someplace/some/random/file`, you can just do `yum install /someplace/some/random/file`

Answer (score 4):

For Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install wbritish
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install wamerican
```

Comment: This answer is not about Fedora.

Comment: It also works for non-English languages, for example `sudo apt-get install wfrench` or `sudo apt-get install wswedish`.