# Fedora localized wordlist package

Tags: linux, fedora

On Debian you can get alternative wordlists to the default `/usr/share/dict/words` by installing `wpolish`, `wgerman` and others.

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/39836/fedora-usr-share-dict-words-file) points how to install the default wordlist on Fedora, and how to install a package given arbitrary path, however running `yum install /usr/share/dict/polish` came up with no results.

Are there localized wordlist packages for Fedora?

Answer (score 1):

I've worked around the problem by downloading manually the package from Debian repository: https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/wpolish, and unpacking the specific file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we (Fedora) do. I don't think for any particular reason; it would probably be useful. However, as a workaround, note that the `hunspell` package comes with dictionaries in many languages. These dictionaries are in the form of base word list with each word having an optional "affix", and an affix file telling the program how to interpret those.

Usefully, there's a command `unmunch` (in Fedora, packaged as part of `hunspell-devel`) which takes these files and generates all of the possible words. So, after installing `hunspell-devel` and `hunspell-pl`, you could do:

```
unmunch /usr/share/myspell/pl_PL.dic /usr/share/myspell/pl_PL.aff
```

to get a list of Polish words. (The character encoding will be found at the top of the `.aff` file — you might want to add `| iconv -f ISO8859-2` to get a more useful encoding.)